# ContractStartDate & ContractEndDate returning dummy dates (1900-01-01 & 4000-01-01) - how can I remove them?

Tags: ssms, powerbi-report-server

ContractStartDate & ContractEndDate returning dummy dates (1900-01-01 & 4000-01-01) - how can I remove them? I'll be using DirectQuery in Power BI to build a report but been asked to remove the "Dummy Dates". Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Select * from(

SELECT [ContactID]
      ,a.[InjixoID]
      ,a.[start_date] as ContractStartDate
      ,a.[end_date] as ContractEndDate
      ,b.EmployeeID
      ,b.[Full name]
      ,c.LeaveDate as CiphrLeaveDate
      ,d.ContractName
      ,d.ContractHours
      ,d.NoOfDays
      ,(ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by a.InjixoID Order by a.[start_date] desc)) as rn
  FROM [Staging].[InjixoContactsbyPU] a

  left join InjixoUsers b on a.InjixoID = b.InjixoID
  left join Employees c on b.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeId
  left join InjixoContracts d on a.ContactID = d.contract_id
  left join InjixoEmployeePeriods e on b.InjixoID = e.employee_id

  where a.end_date >= getdate() 
  --order by b.EmployeeID
  ) t1

  where t1.rn = 1
```

Comment: Add a condition which checks that the values for these columns are posessed in reasonable dates range. For example..

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se! Such dummy dates are a frequently used strategy for missing data. They are an anti-pattern - you should set them to `NULL` and programme accordingly (IMHO).

Comment: Presumably this is the data someone's loading into your table. Like Verace mentions, you should fix the table to store `NULL`s instead but that's a design decision you'll need to work out with whoever else manages that table. Aside from that, why can't you just add a `WHERE` clause to filter out those dummy date values?

Comment: Are you trying to change the display values or eliminate those rows from the results?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am fairly new to this so wanted to ask people with more experience. The above query was written by a former employee, so I didn't want to amend anything just to be on the safe side.  My original thought was to add a WHERE clause in as I only want to change the display to show a BLANK cells for ContractStartDate & ContractEndDate not remove it from the report all together.